# GPG installation compatible with PGP 2.x

Tags: encryption, gpg, pgp

Is it possible to prepare GPG installation with external libraries which is fully compatible with earlier PGP versions (and keyrings)? I read that GPG needs external libraries because of patented algorithms. But are there libraries for all of them and if I have old keyring from DOS version of PGP, can it be used without conversion by GnuPG? If all this can run on Raspberry Pi will be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in compatibility with the old PGP versions is/was the IDEA algorithm, but it looks like the algorithm patent has expired by now.

[From this page](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/why-not-idea.html) you can download an IDEA algorithm plugin for GPG. I think I used it a long time ago for decrypting something encrypted with a very old DOS version of PGP.